# Consume SOAP service in mule flow

Tags: soap, mule, anypoint-studio

[image]

This is my first time that i am using mule.
I had created a simple flow in anypoint studio to consume WSDL. I am able to make contact with WSDL service and generate XML, when the WSDL sends simple string in xml but when WSDL sends user defined object via xml then problem starts, in section of webservice consumer the payload shows error:
"The actual payload metadata does not match the expected one".

It suggest me to add DataMapper element to transform one form to another.

Then i tried mapping and experimenting in Transfprm message component, but unable to resolve the issue.

Please suggest me what to do and how to resolve this.
Below is snap of web service consumer component where payload shows the error:

[image]

Below is image of tansform Message component:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the dataweave transform step make sure you are adding mapping, also Make sure web service you are trying to call is available. Sometimes webservices offline cause problem in mule webservice consumer step.

You can find the samples on exchange https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/?types=WSDL

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you Please tell me how to add mapping? Any Example will be very helpful.

Comment: Here is the link how to use dataweave in studio : https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/using-dataweave-in-studio

Comment: Note : If your HTTP endpoint already generating xml format required for webservice call?, you don't need transformer step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Community Runtime then DataWeaver is not supported. Instead try using CXF component. In order to consume webservice, instead of using HTTP as endpoint, if possible use servlet endpoint.

I had similar scenario where I have published a SOAP and in the implementation of WebMethod I have consumed another SOAP. Please let me know if you need extra information on my approach.